# Acccessing array elements "[]" of a JSON using nlohmann

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have been trying to figure out accessing array elements of a json that are retained inside a square bracket. I need to access the key and value pairs to fill a dictionary.
Accessing Type/name/easy was easy but my understanding of accessing the array elements under "location" and "region" is unclear as I am new to the Json parser [nlohmann library](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/doxygen/index.html)

```
{
            "level1": 
                {
                "Type": {
                    "name": "easy"
                         },
                "location": [
                    {
                        "object": 1,
                        "type": "int"
                    },
                    {
                        "translation": 1,
                        "type": "int"
                    }
                                
                ],
                "region": [
                    {
                        "vpar": 0.05,
                        "type": "float"
                    }
                   ]
        }
    
    }
```

Trying to access json using the following syntax

```
json_level1 = json["level1"]
location = json_level1["location"]
arrayList = location.items(); // Nested json?

    
    for (auto& elment : arrayList)
    {
          // Access to elements
          // e.g.
          // key = "object" : value = 1
          // key = "type" : value = int
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you looking for [this operator](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/doxygen/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a9ea67fc1ef0ccc42e1d5388fe0416ae5.html#a9ea67fc1ef0ccc42e1d5388fe0416ae5)?

Comment: @GiovanniCerretani No no - i am not looking at the operator. If you look at the  JSON i have posted, it contains elements inside "[ ]" brackets. Need to access them. Their keys and values.

Comment: Honestly, it seems that you are looking to that operator. `location[0]` access the first element of the array, and so on. And `items()` is not required, you can iterate directly `location` in a ranged for.